# I want to get my output like this using sql.

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, crosstab

Input:

```
id  type    value
1   a   aa
1   a   aaa
1   b   bb
1   b   bbb
1   c   cc
1   c   ccc
```

Output:

```
id  type_a  type_b  type_c
1   aa;aaa  bb;bbb  cc;ccc
```

using db2 i need to do the work

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT`/`LISTAGG` type of functionality is dependent on the exact SQL implementation you are using.

Comment: I am using db2 for my work , so i have to get the output

Answer (score 0):

Please give some info of Database Version. As different source have different techniques.

Refer below articles for all possible ways of concatenating strings.

[String Aggregation Techniques](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)